# JavaScript. Замена одного из классов у блока другим по клику

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

есть несколько однотипных родительских блоков содержащих дочерние блоки, которым которым присвоено несколько классов. 
 1 группа классы red green blue
 2 группа классы black green blue

```
<div class="parrent">
  <div class="red green blue"></div>
  <div class="red green blue"></div>
  <div class="red green blue"></div>
  <div class="black green blue"></div>
  <div class="black green blue"></div>
  <div class="red green blue"></div>
  <div class="reset">Сбросить</div>
</div>
<div class="parrent">
  <div class="red green blue"></div>
  <div class="red green blue"></div>
  <div class="black green blue"></div>
  <div class="black green blue"></div>
  <div class="black green blue"></div>
  <div class="red green blue"></div>
  <div class="reset">Сбросить</div>
</div>
```

нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "сбросить" класс **black** поменялся на класс **red**, но последовательноть классов осталось как у блоков первой группы (red green blue) строго обязательно или кнопка "сбросить" будет выполнять только визуальную функцию а код в исходное состояние возвращаться не будет. 
пробовал следующие:

```
$(".reset").click(function() {

         $("div.black").addClass('red');
         $("div").removeClass('black');     

});
```

в этом случае все работает, только вот класс **red** прикрепляется в конце
и выглядит это уже так

......

```
<div class="green blue red"></div>
```

.....
вот сделал заготовку:http://jsfiddle.net/cc91juvz/6/
подскажите что сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _код в исходное состояние возвращаться не будет_ непонятно что имеется ввиду под исходным состоянием

Comment: ну вы ж ее не запоминаете перед сбрасыванием, откуда же она должна восстанавливаться?

Comment: у первой группы есть такая вот такие классы: red green blue,в такой вот последовательности\. у второй группы эти классы black green blue нужно чтобы по клику на кнопку сбросить, просто заменился класс black, и чтобы все блоки в коде имели такой вид
  <div class="red green blue"></div> а не <div class="red green blue"></div>
  <div class="green blue red"></div> ну это же не совсем правильно, пусть хоть визуально и срабатывает но если посмотреть в код то последовательность меняется

Comment: вверху прикрепил картинку, посмотрите пожалуйста, вот это же неправильно непорядок что в коде последовательность классов изменилась после нажатия на кнопку сбросить., я так понял, нет способа оставить ее одинаковое red green blue

Comment: Евгений, еще раз: **порядок классов не важен** и посмотрите пост о [ХУ проблеме](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-x-y-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2):

JQuery вам не помошник потому что с т.з. CSS и HTML порядок классов не имеет значения. Если в вашем коде он имеет значение то это баг, исправляйте это. Если вы всё равно хотите сохранять какой то специальный порядок не понятно зачем то обрабатывайте атрибут Class вручную, методы AddClass и RemoveClass работают по спеке а не по вашим странным требованиям.

Comment: может быть есть другие методы которые делают именно замену класса его перезапись? просто если это баг мне большую часть кода модуля придется переписывать так а так как он написан не мной то голову придется поломать прилично

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, я уверен что вы пытаетесь решить какую-то другую придуманную вами проблему. а не ту, которая действительно есть. [X-Y проблема](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-x-y-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-xy-problem) это как раз ваш случай

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов попробуйте что нибудь типа `$(el).attr('class', $(el).attr('class').replace("black", "red"))` но в любом случае это баг вашего модуля, от порядка не должна зависить логика

Comment: понимаю что может быть баг, но это модуль бравирования дат в комнатах, и там слишком много кода привинчено, Поэтому я не могу его точно воспроизвести чтобы показать в чем проблема, поэтому попытался хотя бы какую то упрощенную схему создать. Дело в том что тв самом модуле можно кликнуть по дате заезда а потом по дате выезда, и во всех датах между ними меняется класс, потому когда нажимаю на кнопку сбросить даты меняются обратно, но кода я снова хочу выбрать дату заезда, то он зараза запоминает, ту которую я выбирал в прошлый раз потому что у нее стоит именно оригинальная последовательность

Comment: Ну attr и replace помогли?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, вот вы же сами сказали проблему _кода я снова хочу выбрать дату заезда, то он зараза запоминает, ту которую я выбирал в прошлый раз_ она никак не связана с классами, эти значения наверняка хранятся в самом плагине

Comment: что то не перезаписываются, вот посмотрите попробовал, вроде бы ошибок нет хотя я учусь только http://jsfiddle.net/cc91juvz/10/

Comment: Вы же не скопировали мой код, вы вставили только половину. Надо `$("td").attr('class', $("td").attr('class').replace("black", "red"));`

Comment: а спасибо то что надо, я думал это решит проблему. Теперь понял что надо что то другое думать